# Can React render ejs?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following ejs tags:

```
<%=user.profile.name %>
```

When I compile my React code via Browserify and Reactify (for instance)

```
browserify -t reactify app/dashboard/dashboard.jsx -o build/dashboard.js
```

I get an unexpected token error about my `%=` symbols. Are there ways around this? Or am I not supposed to be mixing React with ejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it can't do that. React uses a special syntax called JSX, which you can use to write your view markup. But JSX actually is just syntactic sugar which the transpiler (eg. reactify) transforms into `React.createElement()` function calls.

Check this section from the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#the-transform